# send multiple messages using web socket server end point in java api

Tags: java, spring, glassfish, websocket

I am trying to implement Java WebSocket api.

I am using [this](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/how-to-build-java-websocket-applications-using-the-jsr-356-api) example for implementation.

My Client End Point Code is as below:

```
package com.java.webSocket;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.DeploymentException;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;

import org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager;

@ClientEndpoint
public class WordgameClientEndpoint {

     private static CountDownLatch latch;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Connected ... " + session.getId());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            System.out.println("session.getId():-- " + session.getId());
            System.out.println("Received ...." + message);
            String userInput = bufferRead.readLine();
            return userInput;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Session %s close because of %s", session.getId(), closeReason));
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();
        try {
            client.connectToServer(WordgameClientEndpoint.class, new URI("ws://localhost:8182/WbSocketDemoTest/game"));

            latch.await();

        } catch (DeploymentException | URISyntaxException | InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

WebSocketServer.java is as below:

```
package com.java.webSocket;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server;

public class WebSocketServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runServer();
    }

    public static void runServer() {
        Server server = new Server("localhost", 8182, "/WbSocketDemoTest", WordgameServerEndpoint.class);

        try {
            server.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Please press a key to stop the server.");
            reader.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            server.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

My Server End points code is as below:

```
package com.java.webSocket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet;

import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason.CloseCodes;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/game")
public class WordgameServerEndpoint {

    private static final Set<WordgameServerEndpoint> connections =  new CopyOnWriteArraySet<WordgameServerEndpoint>();
    //private static final Set<Session> sessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());
    private Session session;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Connected ... " + session.getId());
        this.session = session;
        connections.add(this);
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("message form onOpen of server");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException {
        switch (message) {
        case "quit":
            try {
                session.close(new CloseReason(CloseCodes.NORMAL_CLOSURE,
                        "Game ended"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            break;
        }
        broadcast2(session,message);
    }

    private void broadcast2(Session currentSession, String message){
        for(WordgameServerEndpoint current : connections){
            try {
                System.out.println("in broadcast current.session.getId():-- " + current.session.getId());
                current.session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Session %s closed because of %s",
                session.getId(), closeReason));
    }

}
```

The problem is in broadcast2(Session currentSession, String message) method.

It shows all connected clients but sends message to only one client instead of all.

I want to implement this in spring, so any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can take a look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-websocket if you want to use Spring 4 and Spring Boot.

Comment: @BrianClozel Thanks for reply but in this example they use javascript to connect to server,this approach works fine, but i want to connect server using java on client side.